# How to Build 64-bit native code for android using Expo CLI

Tags: android, react-native, build, 64-bit, expo

I am using react-native and EXPO CLI to build the android apk file. But i cant upload to Play store. I get a warning message

> Warning  This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 1.
>
> From August 1, 2019 all releases must be compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.

Versions that I am using

```html
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
```

Help me out to build app bundle as per Google Play 64-bit requirement.

Comment: Did you have any success? I tried upgrading to expo 33, but I still get a warning in google play ("This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement", "The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code...")

Answer (score 10):

For non-Expo projects above version `0.59`, check your `android/app/build.gradle`. If you have `ndk` set in `defaultConfig`, make sure it contains all architectures `abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"`.

```js
defaultConfig {
  ...
  ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not here yet. That's the answer. https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v33-0-0-is-now-available-52d1c99dfe4c

> We recommend that all Expo developers with Android apps upgrade to SDK 33 now to front-load most of the work required for creating 64-bit APKs, **coming in SDK 34,** and necessary to submit to Google Play in August.

I assume that after the massive changes between 32 and 33, they wanted to split it into 2 separate releases. So, let's assume we'll get the v34 sdk in late July ;)

Comment: @yossi I wanted to call this out for you since you just asked it

Answer (score 4):

Any follow up from expo? It's already the end of may

Comment: According to expo forum, it will support 64 bits well before August: https://forums.expo.io/t/does-expo-package-64-bit-version-of-android/22407

Comment: Did you have any success? I tried upgrading to expo 33, but I still get a warning in google play ("This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement", "The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code...")

Answer (score 0):

The most [recent information](https://forums.expo.io/t/does-expo-package-64-bit-version/18947/2) I could find during the deployment of my app says that expo doesn't produce 64-bit binaries:

> My understanding is that react-native 0.59 will support 64-bit
> versions (currently at “release candidate” stage). Expo 32 is at
> react-native 0.57, I believe.
>
> So far we don’t provide 64 bit binaries, but this is on our roadmap
> and I can promise we will add such feature before this deadline

However, this shouldn't prevent you from deploying your app as the requirement doesn't come into effect until August.

Comment: I separated them by using the "expo eject" and the version is "expo 30," which means we can't upload them to the Google Store?

Comment: If you have ejected you are no longer using expo and my answer no longer applies. Once you are ejected the build process changes but you can produce a 64 bit binary if you react native version is greater than 0.59

Comment: Are you saying that you can create a 64-bit binary, regardless of what you've identified using the "expo eject"?

Comment: i'm using react-native sdk-30

Comment: Is there any indication that the Expo team knows about the August requirement for Android builds and intends to support 64-bit Android builds by that time?

Comment: @pachun: they said Expo will support 64 bits well before August: https://forums.expo.io/t/does-expo-package-64-bit-version-of-android/22407

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Expo SDK 33, my latest Android build (July, 15) is 64bit confirmed:

`Native platforms: arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64`